# SQL Server PIVOT on multiple columns is losing data

Tags: sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2016

I've spent way too much time on this issue, and I'm not getting to the finish line. Please read this through before you run to a conclusion that this is a duplicate of all the other pivot with multiple columns on SO.

We have properties and units, with a table which keeps track of when something changed in the unit. We cannot change the structure of the table, as this is a vendor application.

**Objective**: Pull out the begin and end date for when a unit had an unavailable code of "model".

**Issue**: I need to filter out the dates where it was available in the middle, though that seems to omit one row of data each time (for unit 105).

**what I've tried**: `PIVOT, CROSS APPLY` in conjunction with `LEAD/LAG`

Here's a link to a SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/29592/2/0

The rest of the question has the tsql from the SQLfiddle including the results which I got. The desired result is at the end.

Create table and insert sample data

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS testModelUnit; 
CREATE TABLE testModelUnit(
    propertykey         INT             NOT NULL
    ,unitNumber         VARCHAR(10)     NOT NULL
    ,rowStartDate       DATETIME        NOT NULL
    ,rowEndDate         DATETIME        NOT NULL
    ,unavailableCode    varchar(10)     NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT pk_testModelUnit PRIMARY KEY (propertykey, unitNumber, rowStartDate )
)
GO

INSERT INTO testModelUnit VALUES 

(33,'105',  '2010-11-11 00:00:00.000','2016-11-11 00:00:00.000','MODEL')
,(33,'105', '2016-11-11 00:00:00.000','2016-12-14 07:51:03.307','MODEL')
,(33,'105', '2016-12-14 07:51:03.307','2017-01-01 00:00:00.000',NULL)
,(33,'105', '2017-01-01 00:00:00.00','2017-03-21 12:21:13.703','MODEL')
,(33,'105', '2017-03-21 12:21:13.703','2017-04-21 12:21:13.703','MODEL')
,(33,'105', '2017-04-21 12:21:13.703','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000','MODEL')
,(33,'2606','2017-04-21 12:21:23.207','9999-12-31 00:00:00.000','MODEL')
,(33,'2606','2017-04-19 10:30:09.227','2017-04-21 12:21:23.207','MODEL')
,(33,'2703','2016-12-14 07:51:03.307','2017-04-19 10:29:47.970','MODEL')
,(33,'2703','2011-11-11 00:00:00.000','2016-12-14 07:51:03.307','MODEL')

GO
```

That gives you all the data which you need in order to test it, as unit 105 was available for a short period of time at the end of 2016.

Attempt 1 - use `LEAD/LAG` to determine if a date is the first in a series - then use multiple `PIVOT` statements

```
SELECT
    propertykey         
    ,unitNumber     
    ,firstDate
    ,lastDate   
FROM (
    SELECT 
        propertykey         
        ,unitNumber         
        ,rowStartDate       
        ,rowEndDate     
        ,CASE 
            WHEN propertykey = LAG(propertykey,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                AND unitNumber = LAG(unitNumber,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                AND LAG(rowEndDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) = rowStartDate THEN NULL            
            ELSE 'firstDate'
        END ISFIRST
        ,CASE 
            WHEN propertykey = LEAD(propertykey,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                AND unitNumber = LEAD(unitNumber,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                AND LEAD(rowStartDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) = rowEndDate THEN NULL           
            ELSE 'lastDate'
        END ISLAST
    FROM testModelUnit
    WHERE UnavailableCode = 'model'
) SRC
PIVOT (
    MAX(rowStartDate)
    FOR isfirst in ([firstDate])
) as pivotFirst
PIVOT (
    MAX(rowEndDate)
    FOR islast in ([lastDate])
) as pivotLast
```

Results were:

```
propertykey  unitNumber  firstDate                  lastDate
33           105         NULL                       9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
33           105         2010-11-11 00:00:00.000    NULL
33           105         2017-01-01 00:00:00.000    NULL
33           2606        NULL                       9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
33           2606        2017-04-19 10:30:09.227    NULL
33           2703        NULL                       2017-04-19 10:29:47.970
33           2703        2011-11-11 00:00:00.000    NULL
```

Issue is twofold: firstly, I have the NULLs in different rows, and secondly, I am missing an end date for unit 105 (by reversing the order of the two pivot statements, I reversed the issue, and I was then missing on start date)

Second attempt: use the `LAG/LEAD` as before, though this time use `CROSS APPLY` to get the first/last values into one column and then pivot the result

```
SELECT 
    propertykey
    ,unitNumber
    ,firstDate
    ,lastDate
FROM(
    SELECT
        propertykey
        ,unitNumber
        ,ca.col
        ,ca.value       
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT 
            propertykey         
            ,unitNumber         
            ,rowStartDate       
            ,rowEndDate     
            ,CASE 
                WHEN propertykey = LAG(propertykey,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                    AND unitNumber = LAG(unitNumber,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                    AND LAG(rowEndDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) = rowStartDate THEN NULL            
                ELSE 'firstDate'
            END ISFIRST
            ,CASE 
                WHEN propertykey = LEAD(propertykey,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                    AND unitNumber = LEAD(unitNumber,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) 
                    AND LEAD(rowStartDate,1,NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY propertykey,unitNumber ORDER BY rowStartDate) = rowEndDate THEN NULL           
                ELSE 'lastDate'
            END ISLAST
        FROM testModelUnit
        WHERE UnavailableCode = 'model'
    ) sub
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT ISFIRST, rowStartDate
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ISLAST, rowEndDate
    ) CA (col, value)
    WHERE col IS NOT NULL
)src
PIVOT
(
    max(value)
    for col in ([firstDate],[lastDate])
) AS pivoted
```

Result:

```
propertykey  unitNumber firstDate                 lastDate
33           105        2017-01-01 00:00:00.000   9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
33           2606       2017-04-19 10:30:09.227   9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
33           2703       2011-11-11 00:00:00.000   2017-04-19 10:29:47.970
```

Issue: I got rid of the NULL rows, though I am still missing one record of data for 105

Desired result:

```
propertykey      unitNumber firstDate                 lastDate
    33           105        2010-11-11 00:00:00.000   2016-12-14 07:51:03.307
    33           105        2017-01-01 00:00:00.000   9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
    33           2606       2017-04-19 10:30:09.227   9999-12-31 00:00:00.000
    33           2703       2011-11-11 00:00:00.000   2017-04-19 10:29:47.970
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking query like below?

```
Select PropertyKey, UnitNumber, Min(RowStartDate) as FirstDate, Max(rowEndDate) as LastDate from (
    Select *, Bucket = Row_number() over(partition by propertykey, unitnumber order by rowStartDate) - 
            Row_number() over(partition by propertykey, unitnumber, unavailablecode order by rowStartDate) 
    from testModelUnit
) a
Where a.unavailableCode is not null
group by propertykey, unitNumber, Bucket
```

Output as below:

```
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| PropertyKey | UnitNumber |        FirstDate        |        LastDate         |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|          33 |        105 | 2010-11-11 00:00:00.000 | 2016-12-14 07:51:03.307 |
|          33 |        105 | 2017-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
|          33 |       2606 | 2017-04-19 10:30:09.227 | 9999-12-31 00:00:00.000 |
|          33 |       2703 | 2011-11-11 00:00:00.000 | 2017-04-19 10:29:47.970 |
+-------------+------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

[**Demo**](http://rextester.com/IIVU83999)

Comment: That is brilliant! Avoiding all of the lag/lead stuff. Less = More. Thanks!